# Install my .ipa on a Jailbroken iOS device

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipa

OK, basically this is what I need (and I'm by no means an expert in iOS-related stuff, so... apologies if that sounds too naive...) :

- I'm developping a test app for iPad
- My iOS developer account has expired (so, I can't create certificates/provisioning profiles and all that) and I'm not planning to renew it any time soon
- I want to take my compiled `.ipa` and install it on my Jailbroken iPad (running iOS 7)

Is there any reasonable way to do that? Have you tried that?

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very easy,

**Step 1.** Launch Cydia, search for AppSync Unified

**Step 2.** Install it. (now iTunes will let you sync any IPA to your phone)

***(if search result doesn't show AppSync Unified do the following)***

Tap on the "Manage" button.

Now tap on "Sources" button.
Touch the Edit button and then tap on Add.

Now app this repo –> https://cydia.angelxwind.net/

Once the repo is added, tap Return to Cydia.

Tap on the newly added repo.

Search for AppSync Unified and simply touch it, then select "Install" to start the installation process.

**Step 3.**

Now sync your IPA to your phone using iTunes, Cydia Impactor or by opening the IPA using Filza.

Comment: Hackyouriphone is illegal (it distributes pirated software) and they may be distributing unflod (iPhone malware) with some packages in their repo. __DO NOT USE THAT SOURCE__. Instead, you can either grab the debian package or use a trustworthy/legal source such as cydia.angelxwind.com. Even if you don't care about the legality of your repo, just use something different.

Comment: cydia.angelxwind.com repo not found error from Cydia when trying to add it

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a jailbroken iPhone for a long time, so I am not sure if it's going to work or not, but I know that a jailbreak tweak called AppSync once existed that made this possible. You could try searching for it on Cydia.

Good luck!